# Prevent duplicate string value being referenced in one to many relationship Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have Two models, Participants and Skills, I want to make sure that the Skill name is not duplicated for a certain participant:

**participant.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const participantSchema = new Schema({
    fullname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: false,
        minlength: 8,
    },
    score: {
        type: Number,
        max: 100,
        required: true
    },
    skills: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Skill"
    }]
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

const Participant = mongoose.model('Participant', participantSchema);

module.exports = Participant;
```

**skill.model.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const skillSchema = Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['strength', 'endurance', 'dexterity', 'decision making'],
        required: true
    },
    value: {
        type: Number,
        max: 24
    },
    owner: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Participant",
        required: [true, 'Skill must belong to a participant']
    }
});

const Skill = mongoose.model('Skill', skillSchema);

module.exports = Skill;
```

These are my models, as you can see, skill name has 4 possible values: 'strength', 'endurance', 'dexterity', 'decision making'.

But I need to validate that a participant cannot have strength twice, or endurance twice, it can only be one of them.

How to validate this with Mongoose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You need to create composite unique index on { owner, name } columns.

Long answer:
MongoDB allows you to create unique indices on single column or multiple columns. The unique index ensures that a document with exactly same combination of values on all columns (in index) occurs exactly once in a collection. In your case you want to ensure that each of the enum values can only occur once for any participant (owner). If a unique index were to be created for { owner, name } fields on the collection (that Skill model represents), then MongoDB would ensure that a duplicate value of `name` cannot be saved for any value of `owner`.

You can check how to create composite unique index in Mongo Console [at this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-compound-index).

```
/* Sample */
db.Skills.createIndex({ name: 1, owner: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

You can check how to create composite unique index using Mongoose [at this link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema-index).

```
/* Sample */
skillSchema.index({ name: 1, owner: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Look these docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate

As I see, you can create a validator for your enum and block adding new repeated values for skills array.